# How to make Java GUI application listen to Windows lock screen and unlock screen events?

Tags: java, windows, swing

So, basically I've made a stopwatch GUI application which I want to use for tracking time I spend in front of my PC. I want my stopwatch to stop counting when I lock my PC and resume counting when I unlock my PC. How can this be achieved with Java?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Workstation lock listener using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727879/implementing-workstation-lock-listener-using-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a look at JNA. They provide an example code to listen to Windows events: https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/native_window_msg/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32WindowDemo.java

The example code also includes methods like `onMachineLocked`, `onMachineUnlocked` which might help you.